# Scala plugin in IDEA dosn't work

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-2.8

When i tring to use scala in IDEA it tries to compile java sources and throws
 IO error while decoding path-to-java-file.java with UTF-8

How can I disbale not needed java compilation by scala compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the IDEA Scala plugin, have your project with the Scala Facet, and make sure you have a valid compiler.

I use maven projects so IDEA picks up the configurations.

I would recommend you check the [plugin site](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+for+IntelliJ+IDEA) and the [community](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/scala?view=discussions) for more details.